# Proving Richardson's theorem for constants

Tags: lo.logic, real-analysis, computational-number-theory, decidability

(I asked this a little over 3 months ago [on math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1382945/proving-richardsons-theorem-for-constants), and when I initially re-asked here, no one had responded there. $\:$ After I re-asked here, Eric Towers responded there, since I had forgotten to give a link to here. $\:$ However, his response uses a construction whose expressions are *not* constants.)

Richardson's theorem is given in [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richardson%27s_theorem). $\:$ In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1379799/57159), Eric Towers states that

> - An algebraic expression is decidable.  This is also the [Tarski-Seidenberg theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%E2%80%93Seidenberg_theorem).
> - Algebraic expressions plus $\exp$ are decidable if [Schanuel's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schanuel%27s_conjecture) holds.
>     
>     Otherwise, this is unknown.  See [Tarski's exponential function problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%27s_exponential_function_problem).
> - Throw in sine and determining whether the constant expression vanishes is undecidable.  (This can be linked to the undecidability of models of the integers (a la
>     
>     Godel's Incompleteness Theorems) via the zeroes of $\sin (\pi k)$ for any integer $k$.
>     
>     See [Hilbert's Tenth Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_tenth_problem) and [Matiyasevich's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matiyasevich%27s_theorem#Matiyasevich.27s_theorem).)
>     
>     Sine isn't critical; any (real-)periodic function would do.
>     ​

.

How can the last bullet point of that quote be proven?

Comment: If that last comment means "there is no procedure to decide equality of variable-free expressions in the language $(1,+,-,*,/,\exp,\sin)$", then I think it's unproven.

Comment: @MattF.: Is there any actual such expression whose equality to zero has not been decided?

Comment: @user21820, no.

Comment: @MattF.: Then do you have any intuitive idea for why its decidability has not been proven?

Comment: @user21820, if you suggest an approach, I can probably suggest why it’s not so easy to prove the claim that way.

Comment: @MattF.: I have no idea, which is why I'm asking. I was surprised by your first reply, because I thought that something like $\sin(\exp(\exp(\exp(\exp(\exp(1)))))) = 0$ has not been decided, *and that such an example is well-known and yet nobody knows how to prove or disprove it*. But if hardly anybody tried this example, then is there any example that they did try?

Comment: @user21820, the problem is trivial for expressions using only unary operations. With binary operations like $e^3-e^e-5$ things get more interesting.

Comment: @MattF.: Wait you mean you know the truth-value of my above equation? I would of course guess "false", but why?